# What is the mechanism of Pinia in state updating?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

I'm pretty new to `Nuxt 3` and I'm a bit confused about how `Pinia` works inside components. I create a `vuetify` datatable and bind a list of data from Pinia `state` to datatable's items and I put a search textbox on the top of that which binds to the searchText variable inside store:

```
<v-text-field v-model="store.searchText" prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
      variant="outlined" hide-details></v-text-field>
```

At the component creation time, I call store action to fill the item list by api calling result and it works fine.

```
<script setup>
   await store.getList();
</script>
```

But when I type some words inside searchText, it automatically uses API call and updates the list and I can't figure out How! I tried to use `console.log` inside store actions but nothing was logged. So my question is what is the mechanism of Pinia?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. There's no such "mechanism" in general, it's specific to your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's considered bad practice to mutate `Pinia` store directly.

We know that v-model is sugar syntax, so you can update it like:

```js
<script setup>
// you can call your store whatever you like
const randomStore = useRandomStore()
</script>

<template>
  <v-text-field 
   :model-value="randomStore.searchText" 
   @update:modal-value="randomStore.changeSearchText">
  </v-text-field>
</template>
```

### Best practices to get data from http request:

```js
<script setup>
const randomStore = useRandomStore()
onMounted(async ()=>{
  // use try catch if you want to, but for simplicity i will avoid it
  const res = await getSomeList()
  randomStore.setList(res.data.lists)
})
</script>

<template>
  // we could also add here loading state
  <div v-if="!randomStore.list">
    Loading...
  </div>
  <div v-for=item in randomStore.list :key="item.id">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</template>
```

### To support above code your pinia store should look like this:

```js
export const useRandomStore = defineStore('randomStore', (): State => {
  const searchText= ref<string>('')
  const list = ref(null) // null could be used as loading state

  function changeSearchText(arg:string){
    searchText.value = arg
  }

  function setList(arg){
    list.value = arg || [] // to handle the case when server sends null we should get away from loading state i.e. null
  }

  return { searchText, changeText, list, setList }
})
```

### And to inspect where is your request is triggered you can use DevTools on browser [image]

Answer (score 1):

you should use 'await' in onMounted time ,not created (script setup)

```js
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
onMounted(()=>{
// here
})
```

and I guess your getList function using a getter feild that include searchText state varible.

getter also subscribe field reactive in proxy trigger like vue 'computed' do, so that's how the magic make come true

Hope this helps you